# Read shell output from python line-by-line

Tags: shell, python-2.7

I need to read a shell command output from python script and fill a list with each line:

**ISSUE:**
If I save the command output as a variable, the loop cycle read it character-by-character

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess

CMD = "ls -la"
output = subprocess.check_output(CMD, shell=True)
list = []
for line in output:
    list.append(line)
print list
```

**Bad output:**
['t', 'o', 't', 'a', 'l', ' ', '5',...]

**WORKAROUND:**
As a work around, I directed the comand output to a file, and from there read line-by-line:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess

CMD = "ls -la > tmp"
subprocess.call(CMD, shell=True)
list = []
f = open("tmp", "r")
for line in f:
    list.append(line)
print list
```

**Good output**
['total 52\n', 'drwxrwxr-x  3 ajn ajn 4096 mars  11 17:52 .\n',...]

**QUESTION:**
How can I use the 1st approach (no file manipulation ,all inside the program) with the result of the second approach?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not really a python guy, but this should work for you and seems a bit clearer:

```
import subprocess
cmd = ["ls", "-la"]
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in proc.stdout.readlines():
    print line
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `proc.stdout.readlines()`. This reads all OUTPUT before it returns. You need to use `proc.stdout`.

Here is `yy.py`:

```
import subprocess
cmd = ["bash", "./yy.sh"]

proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in proc.stdout:
    print( line )
```

Here is `yy.sh`:

```
for a in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0; do
    echo "hi $a !!!"
    sleep 1
done
```

When you run `yy.py` you get output line by line.

If you use `proc.stdout.readlines()`, you wait 10 seconds and get all output.

Comment: Super answer! I would also use `line.decode('UTF-8')` to convert the byte sequence to string.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using [`join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)? And use [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) on newline (`\n`).

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess

CMD = "ls -la"
output = subprocess.check_output(CMD, shell=True)
lst = []
for char in output:
    lst.append(char)
print ''.join(lst).split('\n')
```

Basically join all your output into a single string, and then split on the newline character to create a list of your individual outputs. Also it is bad practice to name a variable `list`, as this is a type in Python. Try using `lst` or `list1` instead.

You could also simplify it to:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess

CMD = "ls -la"
output = subprocess.check_output(CMD, shell=True)
print output.split('\n')
```

As the return value of [`subprocess.check_output()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) is the output as a single string, there is no need to loop through each character, just use `split` on the string to get the list of outputs.

Answer (score 1):

Both @glenn-jackman and @tui-popenoe answers work:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in proc.stdout.readlines():
    print line
```

and

```
output = subprocess.check_output(CMD, shell=True)
print output.split('\n')
```

But, I used **subprocess.Popen** because it was useful for piping:

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(['ip','-la'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen(['grep','afile'], stdin=p1.stdout,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p3 = subprocess.Popen(['awk','{ print $6; }'], stdin=p2.stdout,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

output = p3.communicate()[0]

for ln in output.split('\n'):
    print ln
```